# Singular point of this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Firstly, we have only covered ordinary points and regular singular points. We have covered irregular singular points to the point of defining them, but nothing further.

$$x^3y''+(\cos(x)-1)y'-xy=0$$

This can be rewritten as

$$y''+\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^3}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$$

It is obvious that $q(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $x^2q(x)=x^2\frac{1}{x^2}=1$ is analytic at x=0. But my problem is with $p(x)$.

$p(x)=\dfrac{\cos(x)-1}{x^3}$, and so $xp(x)=\dfrac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}$ is not analytic at $x=0$. Thus it would appear that $x=0$ is an irregular singular point.

Unfortunately the professor is not available for a few days, so I'm sort of stuck here. I was told that everything on this assignment should be either ordinary points or regular singular points. Am I missing some trig identity that can simplify this?

Comment: Please consider using \cos to get $\cos$ instead of $cos$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, 
$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac{\sin \frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2
$$
is quite analytical, it has the power series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(k+2)!}
$$
that has in infinite radius of convergence, just as $\cos$, $\sin$ and $\exp$.